# Assign $_POST to var not working

Tags: php

I believe this is dead simple, but i can't see why this isn't working:

content of post.php:

```
<form action="receive.php" />
    <p>input</p>
    <div><textarea id='sendme' name="sendme" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

content of receive.php:

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST)==true && empty($_POST)==false){ 
     $data = $_POST['sendme'];
 }
 echo $_POST['sendme'];
 echo $data;
 ?>
```

result:

nothing :|

Comment: `$_POST` is always set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set in your form `method="post"`, so:

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Also you close `<form>` tag with `/>` - you just shouldn't.

Comment: I should had wait a few seconds before posting this.. just figured that out right now, well, here it go a free point for you Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't  use post method for your form, the `<form>`'s default method is `get`, if you want to send the data by post method, you should do this :

```
<form action="..." method="post"> ... </form>
```

**Note:** After your problem, Note that The global variable `$_POST` is **always** set, if there is no data posted from user, its value is an empty array : `array()`.

So, `isset($_POST)` always returns true.

You must check `if($_POST)`, this ways, you check if `$_POST` is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding the method in the form tag, `method="post"`

Then `print_r($_POST)` to see if you receive anything.

Answer (score 1):

Add method to your Form, else, it will receive it as $_GET['sendme']

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

you must pass method attribute to form tag

```
<form action="receive.php" method = "POST">
```